# Recursion Won't Work

Tags: java, recursion

I am practicing recursion (at least that is what I think I am attempting to do). My expectation is for the code to print out "dlrow olleh" 11 times, but it will only print it once. Reason why?

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Practice {

     public static void main(String[] args){
         String str = "hello world";
         int count = new StringBuilder(str).length();
         System.out.print(backwards(str, count));
     }

     public static String backwards(String word, int letters){

        while(letters>0){
             return new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
        }

        return backwards(word,letters-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to have swapped the base case and the recursive case. Also, you don't need a while loop in recursion, that's what the recursion is for

Comment: But aside from swapping the cases, there is no point in using recursion here: all the recursive calls are doing is decrementing a variable, and then doing something when that value hits zero. Instead, just do that thing straight away. If you want to practice recursion, make sure you are doing something that needs recursion :)

Answer (score 0):

Your base case seems to be triggering first, rather than last. As you will see, if I call backwards("Hello world", 11), then since letters > 0, it will return new `StringBuilder(word).reverse.toString()`.

I think you meant to switch the two around.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you are not modifying the letters variable, so the while wouldn't end.

But return is a statement that breaks the while sentence.

The recoursive approach would be something like this

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    String str = "hello world";
    int count = new StringBuilder(str).length();
    System.out.print(backwards(str, count - 1, new StringBuilder()));
}

public static String backwards(String word, int letters, StringBuilder sb){
    if (letters >= 0) {
        sb.append(word.charAt(letters));
        return backwards(word, letters - 1, sb);
    } else {
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

notice that I'm using count - 1 and letters >= 0 because the index goes from 0 to size - 1